# Exporting SSL session key (from urllib2 / Python SSL implementation)

Tags: python, encryption

Is there a way to save the session key generated during an SSL session ?
As far as I know, this session key is calculated on the server and client side in SSL Handshake using Diffie-Hellman as shown in this image:

[image: as shown in this image]
I am having access to the client side. The client is using urllib2

Comment: What are you going to do with the key?

Comment: I would like to use the session key to decrypt HTTPS traffic.

Comment: The library already does that for you.

Comment: True and I know that. Because I'm developing a code base that is processing unencrypted traffic, I need to manually decrypt HTTPs packets to get integrated into the existing software. Otherwise, the whole code architecture has to be modified and a lot of coding would be needed and there are soon deadlines.

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe someday, perhaps when openssl supports it.